# How Can I change Default table for Auth::attempt() in laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm new to laravel and i am creating a authentication page i need to check the values for authentication in my own table but laravel is checking in users table

as my knowledge we can give in the user model

```
protected $table='my_own_table';
```

but i don't want to do this 
is there any way to change the default table of

```
Auth::attempt()
```

here is my code

```
function handleLogin(Request $request){
$data=$request->only('email','password');
if(\Auth::attempt($data))
{
   return "true";       
}
return "false";
}
```

in the above code when i excute it will check in the user table but i need to check in `my_own_table` is there any solution with out overriding the properties in the `User` model.

Comment: So your users are being stored in the Users table, and you want to authenticate with an emailaddress and password, but not use the Users table?

Comment: No my users are stored in my_own_table. i don't want to use users table at all.

Comment: Settings you are looking for in config/auth.php, change "model" and "table" keys

Comment: How can i change auth.php model and table.User table inherits Authenticatable class if i give my_own_model then how can authentication works